# Prepending branch name to git commit

Tags: macos, git, sed

I've been reading and trying to figure out how to get this to work. I want to prepend the branch name to the commit message so I can just use `git commit -m "message"` and get a commit named `branch message`. The closest I got was to use the following code in `.git/hooks/commit-msg` but I get `sed: 1: ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG": invalid command code .` using OSX 10.8.5.

I read it has something to do with OSX `sed` having different behaviours but I can't find a solution that will work. I probably just don't know enough about OSX/Linux.

```
ticket=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | awk -F'/' '{print $3}')
if [ -n "$ticket" ]; then
    sed -i "1i $ticket " $1
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, OS/X is different.  I tested this and it works ok, but maybe has some additional minor tweaks for you to deal with.  Note that the -i flag on OS X requires a filename extension to save the backup file under, and to avoid sed insisting that the text used to add with 1i must be escaped with \ followed by another line, I used 1s instead.

```
ticket=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | awk -F'/' '{print $3}')
if [ -n "$ticket" ]; then
    sed -i '.bak' "1s/^/$ticket /" $1
fi
```